# Is it possible to solve for x in an equation with both x and ln(x)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation which has the form

$$x=y-c_1\ln(c_2y+c_3)+c_1\ln(c_2x+c_3)$$

where $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are constants, and $y$ is another variable. I am trying to solve it for $x$ but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation is of the form $$x=f(y)+a\ln(bx+c)$$ which is a [transcendental equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) and cannot be solved, in general, to get closed form expressions. However, you can use numerical methods like [Newton-Raphson method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), to solve this.

Comment: Interesting! Can you link me to a source for this, please?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a link for the Newton-Raphson method.

Comment: Oh, I mean could you link me, or explain why ".... $x=f(y)+a\ln(bx+c)$ which is a transcendental equation and cannot be solved"

Comment: Oh, I see. The equation is transcendental, because it involves the transcendental function $e^x$, which you can obtain, applying $e^{(\cdot)}$ to both side of the equation. I have provided a Wikipedia link that contains more discussion on this topic.